# pkgsrc directory linking /usr/pkg with /usr

Tags: bsd, netbsd

I bootstrapped pkgsrc on non-netbsd os, and building applications from source and running the binaries both work.

the `/usr/pkg` directory contains `bin/  etc/  include/  lib/  man/  sbin/  share/` directories, and I can't find any documentation about how packages built with pkgsrc/bmake become systemwide.

Is the `/usr/pkg` directory symlinked to `/usr`? Is there a utility used on top of bmake for installing applications from the pkgsrc tree?

Comment: It appears from some sources that adding the `bin` and `sbin` folders to the default pathname integrates the `/usr/pkg` directory with the rest of the system
http://www.perkin.org.uk/pages/pkgsrc-binary-packages-for-illumos.html

Answer (score 1):

Your comment is correct, you need to add /usr/pkg/bin and /usr/pkg/sbin to your PATH.

You can do that either by modifying your user path in .profile/.cshrc, or system wide by modifying the system versions of the same, usually in /etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still interested. There is a very useful package pkgtools/rc.subr that enables you to use rc.d startup scripts, that are provided by some packages.

For example www/apache22 provides a startup script (it is installed to /usr/pkg/share/examples/rc.d/apache by default). To be able to use it on non-NetBSD systems, you need to copy it to /etc/rc.d (like it's done on NetBSD), and install pkgtools/rc.subr package.